# iOS: Как запретить потребление трафика через WiFi

Tags: ios

Имею ограниченный пакет трафика в день на ноутбуке, который через Wifi раздаю на телефоны. При этом iPhone немерянно потребляет трафик на загрузку - вычерпывает весь пакет 250 MB/сутки. Обновление контента отключено. Автоматические загрузки - отключены. Синхронизация программ с iCloud - отключена, резервное копирование - отключено. Загруженных программ нет. Тем не менее, идет активная закачка на телефон. Посоветуйте, как это побороть.

Comment: посмотрите проксей что он там тянет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился отключением в настройках iOS работы программ с iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была подобная проблема, при этом, телефон безумно быстро садится, а если просто выключить интернет, то все проходит, было это у меня, когда я использовал программа ПОЧТА, стандартная программа, и там было письмо, которое по непонятным причинам не могла отправиться, но отправление шло с бесконечным циклом, в это письмо был вложен так же относительно не большой файл. Попробуйте, моя проблема очень схожа с вашей.